# Endnotes two equal notes in same chapter?

Tags: endnotes

I need to cite as an endnote (with the endnotes package) twice in the same chapter of a document. How do I do it without introducing twice the reference? That is, how do I refer to the same endnote in different parts of the chapter? Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism. The only slight problem is that the `\label` command must go inside the argument to `\endnote`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes,refcount}

\begin{document}

Start\endnote{What?}

Text\endnote{abc\label{dummy}}

More Text\endnotemark[\getrefnumber{dummy}]

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

A couple of LaTeX runs are neeeded, as usual, for the number to stabilize. We need `\getrefnumber` instead of `\ref` because otherwise the first run would fail, since `\endnotemark` needs to see a number (after expansion).

Answer (score 0):

I found the following to be working:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\begin{document}

Text\endnote[1]{abc}

More Text\endnotemark[1]

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

Basically you define a counter and then just refer to it via `\endnotemark[num]` however I'm not sure whether that means you have to manually adjust all the counters.